# How to insert multiple hyperlinks in a single cell?

Tags: vba, image, excel, hyperlink

I need a way to have multiple links inside a single cell in Excel using VBA. I have an excel sheet will cells like this:

[image]

And I need to have 3 links inside a single cell with each link pointing to a different file then how do I have multiple links a single cell?

Answer (score 2):

We can accomplish this by inserting small images in the cell and adjusting them appropriately.

The user will be able to click on [image] and open the corresponding file. The cell finally looks like below:

[image: The images in the cell]

[image]  Download [link.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz0dl.png)

The function:

```
'Put this in your module

Sub PutLinksInACell()
    Dim rangeAddress As String
    Dim fileArray
    fileArray = Array("144234\SDFsdf0fghf10_144234.pdf", "144234\ghfrg35bzb-20-1_R04.docx", "144234\xcvbebeEN 113.pdf")
    'rangeAddress = Selection.Cells(1, 1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
    insertPicture Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\link.png", "A1", fileArray
End Sub

Sub insertPicture(picpath As String, cellAddress As String, fileArray As Variant)
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' "THE BURGER-WARE LICENSE" (Revision 42):
    ' <abybaddi009 gmail.com> wrote this code. As long as you retain this notice you
    ' can do whatever you want with this stuff. If we meet some day, and you think
    ' this stuff is worth it, you can buy me a burger in return. ;-) -Abhishek Baddi
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Dim spacing As Long, size As Long

    size = Range(cellAddress).Font.size
    spacing = size * 0.2

    x_coor = Range(cellAddress).Cells(1, 1).Left
    y_coor = Range(cellAddress).Cells(1, 1).Top

    For i = 1 To 3
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(picpath).Select
        With Selection
            With .ShapeRange
                .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                .Height = size
            End With
            .Left = x_coor + 5
            .Top = y_coor + size * (i - 1) + spacing * i
            .Placement = 1
            .PrintObject = True
        End With

        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1), Address:= _
            fileArray(i - 1)

        Range(cellAddress).Select
    Next
    Range(cellAddress).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    Range(cellAddress).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
End Sub
```